# Objects only rendered in Left orthographic view

Tags: import, viewport, mesh, 3dsmax, 3ds

**HOW THE Viewports look after loading the file:**
[image: HOW THE Viewports look after loading the file]

I am having an issue caused by extremely large objects (in terms of physical size not polycount etc.) that I imported from a game using ninjaripper (a script used for extracting 3d models from games). When I open the file containing these large objects, the objects are only rendered in the left orthographic viewport. All other viewports/views do not show the geometry regardless of which rendering mode (wireframe, edges faces etc.) I have selected on said viewports. The objects are also not visible in perspective views. When I unhide all items apart from a single object (of normal size) I am able to see the object in all viewports including perspective viewports. When I unhide all again, the object which could previously be seen disappears. When switching to perspective view when these extremely large objects are present, the 'viewcube' disappears for an unknown reason. Zooming in or out in a perspective viewport also results in the viewcube disappearing. This is the only scene I've had so far which shows these issues, all my graphics drivers are up to date (specs listed below). The scene contains 3602 objects and has 1,957,286 polygons and 1,508,550 vertices.

**This is the furthest I could zoom out in 3ds max:**
[image: The furthest I could zoom out in 3ds max]

**Viewcube has disappeared on top right and bottom right viewport:**
[image: Viewcube has disappeared on top right and bottom right viewport]

I tried removing all of the extremely large objects by hand, after which the remaining (normal sizes) objects could be seen in 2 of the viewports (top left and top right viewport did render correctly). 
**Viewports after having deleted all extremely large objects:**
[image]

I tried resetting the scene, after which I merged the scene containing all 'normal sized objects' into an empty scene. This resulted in all viewports rendering the objects correctly. However, after saving the file and re-opening the saved file, 2 of the 4 viewports did not render the objects as was the case after just having deleted all but the 'normal sized' objects.

**My question is:** how should I deal with these extremely large imported objects in order to fix the viewport rendering issues they cause?

I wrote a simple bit of maxscript code to print out the maximum size of the biggest object in the scene, which resulted in a value of 2.6*10^38 [generic units], which, according to my calculation corresponds to a value of 6.6*10^36 [meters], in summary: extremely large. (I suspect the ninjaripper script or the script which imports the files produced by the ninjaripper into 3ds max had some sort of error causing some of the vertices to have extremely large position values). When I switch to the measure tap in 'utilities' and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all objects in the scene (the scene containing all objects including the extremely large objects), 3ds max crashes due to the large object size (error message: "Application error- An error has occured and the application will now close. No Scene changes have occured since your last save.").

I could write some maxscript code which deletes all objects which are larger then a certain size (for example: 10^5 [meters]). However, as afore mentioned this for some reason does not fix the issue completely (after saving the scene with only 'normal sized' objects and re-opening the scene only 2 of the 4 viewports render the objects correctly. I ran the code for measuring the max size of the largest object in the scene again after having deleted all extremely large objects to check if I had indeed not skipped over one of these large objects, the result was a value of: 121.28 [generic units] (corresponding to object: "Mesh_3598") which is a relatively normal size, however 2 of my 4 viewports are not rendering my objects even after deleting the large objects (only when the left orthographic view is selected they can be seen in the 2 viewports that do not render part of the time).

**Code for checking largest object (also prints out maximum size of this object):**

```
global_max=0
largest_obj=undefined
for obj in geometry do(
    obj_max_x = (obj.max.x-obj.min.x)
    obj_max_y = (obj.max.y-obj.min.y)
    obj_max_z = (obj.max.z-obj.min.z)
    local_max = amax(#(obj_max_x, obj_max_y, obj_max_z ))
    if local_max > global_max do 
        global_max = local_max ; largest_obj = obj
        )
messagebox ("global max = " + global_max as string)
messagebox ("largest obj = " + largest_obj as string)
```

**See the following links for the 3ds max scene files I have mentioned:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bAilmaHAXDr4WuD8gGS4piQfPzzJM9MH

**Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!**

**System specs:**

-Autodesk 3ds max 2018 x64

-Windows 10 PRO x64

-i5 6600k @3.5ghz

-msi z170a gaming m7 - socket 1151 - atx

-coolermaster g750m -750watt

-msi radeon r9-390x gaming -8gb

-noctua NH-D15

-kingston hyper-x fury black 16gb-pc-21300-dimm-4x4gb@2666mhz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the extremely large objects were indeed causing the viewport rendering error. After removing all object's with a maximum size of 100000 [generic units] the viewport rendering errors were gone. I suspect the issue was caused by the objects not being in between the viewport's far and near planes due to the extremely large object sizes.